# Insert into tablename Set Example in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Mysql query:

How to change the query into postgresql?

```
INSERT into tablename SET a=10, b=20, c=30
```

Answer (score 8):

PostgreSQL does not support syntax INSERT...SET (mysql does).

But another systax can be something you need:

with full fields:

```
INSERT into tablename
       SELECT 10 AS a, 20 AS b, 30 as c;
```

with specific fields:

```
INSERT into tablename (b, c)
       SELECT 20 AS b, 30 as c;
```

Comment: This solution not working

Answer (score 2):

[Insert](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) Query:

```
INSERT into tablename(a,b,c) values (10,20,30)
```

[Update](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) Query:

```
update tablename SET a=10, b=20, c=30 where <conditions...>
```

Comment: i want this query in postgresql

Comment: @selva This is the query, you're confused with something that missing in the question and my answer is the way to insert/update data in any  DB including PostgreSQL

Comment: To add some caution for anyone reading this - if you use that `update` statement then it will set those values for ALL records in your database. Not just a new record. It's SUPER dangerous